# Как с помощью PHP заменить дату в строчке MySQL на сегодняшнюю?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

В базе **MySQL** имеется таблица `aw_info`, в ней хранятся объявления.

В ней имеются, среди прочих, следующие столбцы:

- `id` (первичный ключ)
- `postdate` (дата подачи)

Как при редактировании объявления админом записать в `postdate` сегодняшнюю дату?

Comment: а какой тип у вашего `potdate` ?

Answer (score 1):

Получаете сегодняшнюю дату на php `date("d-m-Y")` и отправляете запрос на обновление строки в таблице

Comment: Знал бы, когда я ставлю дату сбивает на 1970 год. форма такая на сайте **2015-11-24-21-44**

Comment: Попробуйте параметры передаваемые в функцию даты поменять. Т.е. получится что-то подобное "Y-m-d-H-mm" , не уверен точно правильно ли написал, уточните в документации к функции

Comment: ВЫ можете написать полный год пожалуйста, а то столько всякого, голова летит уже.

Comment: @АлександрКовалёв date("Y-m-d-G-i")

Comment: @АлександрКовалёв вроде так, пишу с телефона, поэтому могу и сам ошибаться маленько. Как дополнение взято это отсюда http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

Comment: Том то и дело я уже весь инет перечитал и вот не понимаю.

Comment: @АлександрКовалёв можете привести пример Вашего кода ?

Comment: Я его уже удалил, так как не работал, уже не знаю за что браться. Там был php код с подключением к базе mysql, потом через update форму, но дату сбивало на 1970 год. Мне бы кто написал код, Хотя бы похожий что то, сразу бы понял, а так как баран на новые ворота((

Comment: Мне скинули

<form name='date_change' action='' method='POST'>
Сегодня     <input type='text' name='data_today' value='<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>'>
<input type='submit' name='reset' value='Обновить'>
</form>
<?php
include ("setup.php");
    if (isset($_POST['reset'])) { 
    $date = $_POST['data_today'];
        $rs = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `table_name` SET `postdate` = '$date' WHERE `id` = 3") or die(mysqli_error());
    }
?>

Comment: Попробуйте переменную даты задать так и проверить  $data=date("Y-m-d-G-i")

Comment: Вставил код, показывается форма, показывается дата сегодня, кнопка обновить дату И под низом ошибки 2
**Warning: include(/setup.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /h/stroyuslugiby/htdocs/admin/templates/edit_info.htm on line 251

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/setup.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /h/stroyuslugiby/htdocs/admin/templates/edit_info.htm on line 251**

Comment: Это уже ошибки в путях к подключаемым файлам как я понял

Comment: Ошибку устранил, но при  нажатие на кнопку Обновить, перекидывает на предыдущую страницу

Comment: @АлександрКовалёв я не знаю Вашего полного кода, тут мне тяжело подсказать.единственное разбираетесь с обработкой пост данных и смотрите куда они отправляются

Comment: При нажатие вот выдаёт ответ не понятный

**Table 'stroyuslugiby.avtor1' doesn't exist**

Comment: Дорогой человек ) я же не буду писать за вас все ) это простые ошибки которые понятны даже без гугла. Более того примеров реализации очень много, Вам лишь нужно проявить внимательность и сообразительность ) и помните , лучше ничего не делать чем делать что-то через попу да и находить себе проблем, трудностей ) порой лучше отдохнуть и посмотреть на все трезвым не замвленым взглядом )

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-database/thread1591796.html#post8390198

Вот последнее сообщение самое, там всё написано, что до как, но с датой косяк, при обновение меняет дату не теперешнюю, а 1970-01-01-03-33

Comment: @АлександрКовалёв Ну вот вы на 13 строке переменной даты присваиваете значение из инпута, Вы объявить эту

Comment: Переменную иначе, т.е. вместо того чтобы брать значение с формы, заполните его сразу как я говорил выше,

Comment: Функция MySQL - **now()** выдает текущие дату и время в формате **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS**. Запрос - **"UPDATE table_name SET postdate = now() WHERE id = 3"**